# how to solve Spring boot Procfile heroku error

Tags: java, spring-boot, github, heroku, procfile

I am new in heroku trying to deploy my first spring boot project on heroku using github but I am getting error:

> at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET.

I did small R&D and got to know that i have to add the Procfile to the github. So After adding the ProcFile still I am getting the error:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile
> target/reactfull-webservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Please any one can suggest what should I change .

Errror I am getting

```
 Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=42877 -jar target/reactfull-webservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
2021-04-07T09:30:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-04-07T09:30:17.677364+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2021-04-07T09:30:17.678838+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile target/reactfull-webservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2021-04-07T09:30:17.758735+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-07T09:30:17.824379+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-04-07T09:30:25.109822+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=springappwebproject.herokuapp.com request_id=fbabdc3f-eb42-4f06-9953-00c049907228 fwd="49.36.161.143" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-07T09:30:25.679219+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=springappwebproject.herokuapp.com request_id=451f2812-71cb-4f72-9e45-edbef79dc31f fwd="49.36.161.143" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Procfile file

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/reactfullwebservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

.gitignore file

```
HELP.md
target/
!.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar
!**/src/main/**/target/
!**/src/test/**/target/

### STS ###
.apt_generated
.classpath
.factorypath
.project
.settings
.springBeans
.sts4-cache

### IntelliJ IDEA ###
.idea
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr

### NetBeans ###
/nbproject/private/
/nbbuild/
/dist/
/nbdist/
/.nb-gradle/
build/
!**/src/main/**/build/
!**/src/test/**/build/

### VS Code ###
.vscode/
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myfirstdemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactfull-webservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>reactfull-webservice</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: This `2021-04-07T09:30:17.678838+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile target/reactfull-webservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` should tell you what is wrong. Especially because your packaging is `war` and not `jar`.

Comment: should i replace jar with war

Comment: web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/reactfullwebservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war I have changed this but still getting the error  web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/reactfullwebservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

Comment: web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -war target/reactfullwebservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war When i changed this its showing    Unrecognized option: -war    What should i changed

Comment: You have changed what into what and what error? Adding additional information as comments makes it totally unreadable, instead edit your question. Why did you change -jar to -war.. You only need to change the name of the artifact.